# using grep as input for pexpect

Tags: python, grep, pexpect

I'm trying to use grep command with pexpect but expect function seems to be picking  up everything which was in the sendline before.

eg.

```
child.sendline("grep text somefile.txt")
ret = child.expect['text', 'root@*' ]
```

I will always get 0 as output even if 'text' string is not in somefile.txt.
How to correctly use it to get 0 if it finds the string in the file and 1 if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Most spawned connections will echo by default. You can either turn off echo before you send the grep command (with `child.setecho(False)`), or add another `expect()` just after the `sendline()` that matches for the command you just sent.